# How to get the accurare height of the visiable portion of window on IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to get the visible height of my page, but on IE no matte what I try the height retuned is less than the actual height, for instance [image: this image] is a snip of the visible portion of my page, and its actual  height is 954 pixels or so, but the code `$(window).height()` is returning 816, and running the same scrip on chrome gives the exact height number.

Any ideas and workarounds are welcome, and as a note, I already tried the first 50 hits on google.

Comment: do you have developer tools open when doing this? What makes you say it is 954px if the internals of the browser tell you it's not?

Comment: Testing this on chrome gave 954, and when I measured the height of the of the page (as an image) it was 954 as well, its just IE not giving the correct page height...

Comment: I just tried `window.innerHeight` and the value is also incorrect on IE, in the image above `offset().top` for "Country Of Incident" is greater than the window.height on IE, so that's  a proof that it isn't working properly on IE